# ActionScript 3 TransformGestureEvent not working on SWF MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Good Afternoon All,

I added an SWF to my stage and converted it to a MovieClip, I gave that MovieClip and instance name of floorplanMC and now I am trying to apply TransformGestureEvent to floorplanMC but when I goto test it out, its doesn't work as well as if I were to go the exact same steps but with a jpg instead of an SWF, it only responds sometimes to the TransformGestureEvent, but with a jpg it responds every time. Why doesn't this work with SWF but does with JPG?

Here is my code:

```
floorplanMC.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, zoomFloorplan);
floorplanMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragStartFloorplan);
floorplanMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragEndFloorplan);
```

and here are the methods

```
function zoomFloorplan (event:TransformGestureEvent):void{

    myTimerModel.stop();
    myTimerModel.reset();
    myTimerModel.start();

    var locX:Number=event.localX;
    var locY:Number=event.localY;
    var stX:Number=event.stageX;
    var stY:Number=event.stageY;
    var prevScaleX:Number=floorplanMC.scaleX;
    var prevScaleY:Number=floorplanMC.scaleY;
    var mat:Matrix;
    var externalPoint=new Point(stX,stY);
    var internalPoint=new Point(locX,locY);

    floorplanMC.scaleX *= event.scaleX;
    floorplanMC.scaleY *= event.scaleY;

    if(event.scaleX > 1 && floorplanMC.scaleX > 6){
    floorplanMC.scaleX=prevScaleX;
    floorplanMC.scaleY=prevScaleY;
    }

    if(event.scaleY > 1 && floorplanMC.scaleY > 6){
    floorplanMC.scaleX=prevScaleX;
    floorplanMC.scaleY=prevScaleY;
    }

    if(event.scaleX < 1.1 && floorplanMC.scaleX < 1){
    floorplanMC.scaleX=prevScaleX;
    floorplanMC.scaleY=prevScaleY;
    }

    if(event.scaleY < 1.1 && floorplanMC.scaleY < 1){
    floorplanMC.scaleX=prevScaleX;
    floorplanMC.scaleY=prevScaleY;
    }
    mat=floorplanMC.transform.matrix.clone();
    MatrixTransformer.matchInternalPointWithExternal(mat,internalPoint,externalPoint);
    floorplanMC.transform.matrix=mat;
}

function dragStartFloorplan(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    myTimerModel.stop();
    myTimerModel.reset();
    myTimerModel.start();
    if(floorplanMC.scaleX > 1 && floorplanMC.scaleY > 1)
    {
        floorplanMC.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(0,500,-floorplanMC.width + stage.stageWidth, -floorplanMC.height + 1187));
    }
}

function dragEndFloorplan(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    myTimerModel.stop();
    myTimerModel.reset();
    myTimerModel.start();
    floorplanMC.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

The events will only fire over portions of your SWF that have a background.  Transparent regions will not fire an event.

A simple solution would be to draw a sprite layer inside of your child SWF.

```
var bg:Sprite = new Sprite();
bg.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
bg.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight)
bg.graphics.endFill();
addChild(bg);
```

---

## Demonstration

To demonstrate, we'll create two `.swf` files. The first one (the child) only has a series of bars.  There are no event listeners whatsoever.

```
// Child.swf

var size:Number = 50;
for (var i:int = 0; i < stage.stageWidth/(size*2); i++) {
    var box:Sprite = new Sprite();
    box.graphics.beginFill(0x008cc6);
    box.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, stage.stageHeight)
    box.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(box);
    box.x = i * (size*2);
}
```

The second (the parent) loads the child and attaches listeners to the loader (the topmost container for our swf).  If you click on a bar, all the bars turn green.  However, notice that clicking the whitespace between the bars produces no results.

```
// Parent.swf

import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import fl.motion.Color;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("child.swf"));
addChild(loader);

loader.addEventListener("mouseDown", cursor);
loader.addEventListener("mouseUp", cursor);

function cursor(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var box:Sprite = e.target as Sprite;
    var c:Color = new Color();

    if (box != null) {
        switch (e.type) {
            case "mouseDown":
                c.setTint(0x00d719, 1);
                loader.transform.colorTransform = c;
                break;
            case "mouseUp":
                c.setTint(0x00, 0);
                loader.transform.colorTransform = c;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's recompile the child with the background code provided in the solution.  Here is the modified child code.

```
// Child

var bg:Sprite = new Sprite();
bg.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
bg.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight)
bg.graphics.endFill();
addChild(bg);

var size:Number = 50;
for (var i:int = 0; i < stage.stageWidth/(size*2); i++) {
    var box:Sprite = new Sprite();
    box.graphics.beginFill(0x008cc6);
    box.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, stage.stageHeight)
    box.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(box);
    box.x = i * (size*2);
}
```

Compile the parent, and you'll notice that clicking anywhere (including between the bars) will generate the event.

Comment: So I draw this shape and then add the MovieClip floorplanMC to bg via bg.addChild(floorplanMC) and then add my eventListeners to the bg and in my zoom method apply the zooms to floorplanMC or bg?

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: Draw the shape inside of your SWF.  Compile that, then load the swf into your parent.  On the parent, you add the event listener to your swf, (as if it were a JPG).

Comment: Can you include the part about "Drawing the shape inside the SWF" in your answer so I am clear, cause it sounds like I add floorplanMC to bg shape

Comment: I'll drum up an example.  Give me a moment.

Comment: @user979331 if the Answer works then mark it as solution & upvote. Thanks

Comment: Im trying to apply the code to my code, bare with me.